# ifram and embed tag is not working on wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am new here buddies.
I have a little problem. I just create a new blog on wordpress free. I want to broadcast live channels. When i try to insert "iframe" tag it remove automatically. And then try "embed" tag.
I searched for solution but did not find any solution. Everyone refers plugin but in free wordpress we can not add plugin.
Is there any way?? please help

Comment: check this url
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes/3067#3067

Comment: If you're using WordPress.com (not hosting it yourself) you can't use `<iframe>` tags or install plugins. There is a [list of allowed HTML tags](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#html-tags). You'll need to use the [self hosted version](http://wordpress.org/) of WordPress.

Comment: Buddy i can not edit theme in free wordpress blog. Without editing is there any way??

Comment: Is there any way to add live streaming on my blog??
I have proper rights.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that on the free version. You'll need to get your own webhost and install WordPress on it to do what you want.